# difficulties implementing queue by linked- list in java

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

recently I read an implementation of enqueue in java, and become really confused at the meaning of couple lines in it.

```
public void enqueue(String item) {
    Node oldlast = last;
    last = new Node();
    last.item = item;
    last.next = null;

    if (isEmpty())
        first = last;
    else
        oldlast.next = last;
}
```

I'm confused that since oldlast is created only in this method, why would we state "oldlast.next= last" after else? it would be destroyed after the method, right?

Also, if we only add last to first when first is empty, would it be buggy if I add two nodes then delete two? Since only one node is added to first and I want to delete two would there be exception?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void enqueue(String item)
{
    Node oldlast = last; // last points to some Node_A, oldlast also will point at the same object
    last = new Node(); // Now last points to new object (Node_B), old last still points to Node_A
    last.item = item;
    last.next = null;
    if (isEmpty()) first = last;
    else oldlast.next = last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`oldLast` is not *created*, it simply is a reference to the same object as `last`.

```
public void enqueue(String item)
{
    Node oldlast = last; // oldLast -> nodeX, last -> nodeX
    last = new Node(); // oldLast -> nodeX, last -> nodeY
    last.item = item;
    last.next = null;
    if (isEmpty()) first = last;
    else oldlast.next = last; // change the nodeX
}
```